# Simple xml document with Css

Tags: css, xml

Hi i am new in programming i am creating a simple xml document and i want to apply Css in my xml data . My xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE Customers SYSTEM "customers.dtd">
    <Employees>
      <Employee>
      <FirstNameLabel>FirstName:</FirstNameLabel>
            <FirstNameData>Ana</FirstNameData>
          <FirstNameLabel>LastName:</FirstNameLabel>
            <FirstNameData>Ali</FirstNameData>

        </Employee>

     <Employee>
      <FirstNameLabel>FirstName:</FirstNameLabel>
            <FirstNameData>Ash</FirstNameData>
          <FirstNameLabel>LastName:</FirstNameLabel>
            <FirstNameData>Ana</FirstNameData>

        </Employee>
     </Employees>
```

I need to display results as

```
FirstName: Ana
LastName: Ali

FirstName: Ash
LastName: Ana
```

While FirstName and LastName should be green while Values should be red

Help would be appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you looked before posting this. w3schools shows exactly how. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_display.asp It is very similar to adding a style sheet to html. Also, you should fix your indentation.

Comment: but i want my result like
Labels should be in green and value should be in red

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
FirstNameLabel{
  float:left;
}
FirstNameData{
  clear:left;
}
```

Comment: Did you use something like `<?xml-stylesheet type='text/css' href='yourCSS.css'?>` directly below your `version`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to look to use [XML Stylesheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_stylesheet) to render and format your XML files rather than CSS. CSS is, as far as I know, for HTML documents. In your case, you would need to create a XSLT sheet, which is pretty much XML that specifies how to present each of your node. below is a quick example (untested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:for-each select="Employees/Employee">
       <p>Firstname: <xsl:value-of select="FirstNameData"/>.</p>
       <p>Lastname: <xsl:value-of select="LastNameData"/>.</p>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that you shouldn't need to store labels in your XML. You can have them in your stylesheet.